# Gparted will not let my edit and do changes to my partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to shrink my /dev/sda1 partition but gparted will not let me do any editing and alterations to anything. Note that everything is in gray, so that I cannot edit anything. How can I fix this? I'm using an HP 635 Notebook PC for the record.
Thanks.
[image: note the gray areas]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the options are grayed out because the partition you're trying to resize is mounted and is a root partition. Any partition has to be unmounted before resize/move/delete and there's no way to unmount root partition while running Ubuntu. Whereas you can mount other partitions by simply right click and select unmount. So boot from a Live CD/USB and then you can resize the root partition but make sure to backup you data before doing so.

Comment: While not applicable directly to the Asker's screenshot, that little lock icon (to the right of the partition string) can appear next to logical volumes that are `Active`, in which case it's necessary to right-click and `Deactivate` them before attempting to move/resize.